# set bottom of page to bottom of div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a grid of divs that when clicked reveal a div beneath their current row.
I'd like it so if the user clicked a div on the bottom row - the page would scroll so that the revealed div was now aligned to the bottom of the screen (so that the user would know the div was there and it wouldn't be hidden off screen)

I've tried using jquery scrollTop as

```
  $('body').scrollTop(div);
```

and this sets the div to the top of the page - but how can I align to the bottom - also can I animate this transition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(function(){ 
    var element = $('#align-this')
$('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: element.offset().top + element.height() - $(window).height()
    }, 2000);
}).call()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1drnuabg/2/
Do test for edge cases though, (element being too high to scroll down, etc)